# Ignore type casting IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem .

```
mysql> SELECT 0 IN ('a',4);
+--------------+
| 0 IN ('a',4) |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1 IN ('a',4);
+--------------+
| 1 IN ('a',4) |
+--------------+
|            0 |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

'a' casting to 0.How to make that 'a' not been casting..?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: If you're testing numbers, why are you including non-numeric strings in the `IN` list?

Comment: You are warned by the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) not to do this: _You should never mix quoted and unquoted values in an IN list because the comparison rules for quoted values (such as strings) and unquoted values (such as numbers) differ. Mixing types may therefore lead to inconsistent results. For example, do not write an IN expression like this:

`SELECT val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val1 IN (1,2,'a');`_

Comment: See also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36100/11651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the value you're comparing to a string:

```
mysql> SELECT '0' IN ('a', '4');
+-----------------+
| '0' IN ('a', 4) |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+

mysql> SELECT '4' IN ('a', '4');
+-----------------+
| '4' IN ('a', 4) |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
```