# MySQL 0 IN ("Some", "Set")

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, clause

I've got a MySQL query which uses IN clause.

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeOtherColumn IN ('Some', 'Set')
```

However, I've stumbled upon a case, where SomeOtherColumn has a value of 0, and MySQL evaluates the where clause as TRUE:

```
SELECT 0 IN ('Some', 'Set')
```

Evaluates to

```
1 (TRUE)
```

MySQL version 5.5.46. Anyone has any idea why it happens so?

Comment: This begs the question: Why are you comparing a numeric column to a set of character based values?

Comment: This questions seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929344/ignore-type-casting-in

Comment: It is used as part of general combo search field and searches through many columns like name, last name and some external ID which happend to be a 0. Ps. Indeed a duplicate though I haven't found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `0` is interpreted as a numeric literal.

The values in the parens are also evaluated as numeric literals. And both of the values in the IN list evaluate to a numeric value of `0`.

(Unlike other databases, MySQL is somewhat generous in the implicit conversion to numeric. Rather than throwing an "Invalid number" error, it does the best it can, and returns a result.)

Compare to:

Evaluate as string literal and the comparison:

```
 SELECT '0' IN ('Some','Set')
```

Evaluate as numeric literals:

```
 SELECT 0 IN ('1foo','2bar')
```

Test conversion to numeric:

```
 SELECT 'Some' + 0, 'Set' + 0

 SELECT '1foo' + 0, '2bar' + 0
```

Comment: And to answer the question you didn't ask: "how do I fix this?"... it depends on what behavior you want.  If you want to perform a string comparison, then cast/convert `SomeOtherColumn` to character datatype. There's several ways to do that. You could use a `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` function.  e.g.  **`WHERE CONVERT(SomeOtherColumn,CHAR) IN ('Some', 'Set')`**

Comment: I fixed it by casting to CHAR in the beginning bit I was wandering why it works that way. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `0` to `varchar`:

`select '0' in ('Some', 'Set')` will evaluate to `0`.